# Android (Java) - Fill ArrayList by means of recursive method

Tags: java, android, recursion, arraylist

I'm developing book reader that opens epub files.I searched a lot on the internet and finally found a solution in this [tutorial link](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android).

---

But now i'm experiencing trouble with the method

**logTableOfContents(List tocReferences, int depth)**

*I mofided it from void to String,it is my code*

```
 private String logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {

    if (tocReferences == null) {




        return null;
    }

    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            tocString.append("\t");
        }

        tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());

        //Toast.makeText(this, ""+ logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return tocString.toString();

    }

    return null;
}
```

---

It can be clearly seen that developer who prepared that tutorial have used Recursive method in order to get *Table Of Contents*.

---

I changed method void to String to get and store them in the ArrayList
,however couldn't get Book's table of content individually out of recursive method.Got nullPointerException when tried to Log elements of ArrayList.

---

Now i want to get help from someone to solve this issue,any recommendation will be welcome,Thanks in advance.

---

Code from [tutorial](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) that i used

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
 
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TOCReference;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
 
/**
 * Log the info of 'assets/books/testbook.epub'.
 *
 * @author paul.siegmann
 *
 */
public class LogTestBookInfo extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
      // find InputStream for book
      InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
          .open("books/testbook.epub");
 
      // Load Book from inputStream
      Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
 
      // Log the book's authors
      Log.i("epublib", "author(s): " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());
 
      // Log the book's title
      Log.i("epublib", "title: " + book.getTitle());
 
      // Log the book's coverimage property
      Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage()
          .getInputStream());
      Log.i("epublib", "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() + " by "
          + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");
 
      // Log the tale of contents
      logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    }
  }
 
  /**
   * Recursively Log the Table of Contents
   *
   * @param tocReferences
   * @param depth
   */
  private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
      return;
    }
    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
      StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        tocString.append("\t");
      }
      tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
      Log.i("epublib", tocString.toString());
 
      logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

---

*Libraries that i used have been written in the tutorial.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just founded a solution to my question.

---

I added a new parameter to my logTableOfContent(..., ..., ArrayList ...) method and modified it:

---

```js
private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth, ArrayList<String> ListOfContents) {

        if (tocReferences == null) {


            return;
        }

        for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
            StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                tocString.append("\t");
            }

            tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());

            Log.v("TAG", tocString.toString());

            ListOfContents.add(tocString.toString());

            logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1, ListOfContents);

            //return tocString.toString();

        }

    }
```

---

The void method can be used as

```
 ArrayList<String> TableOfContent = new ArrayList<>();

        logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0, TableOfContent);

        for (String string:TableOfContent){

            Toast.makeText(this, ""+ string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

---

Thanks to much those who spared time to review the question.

---